# Building vector from a double for loop using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, iteration, rcpp, armadillo

I am learning how to use iterators, but I am having trouble conceptualizing how to use them to construct a vector from a  double loop.

Here is an example: lets say I want to write a function that inputs two vectors, and outputs a vector of all the possible sums generated by combining a single element from each vector (this is a contrived example). Here is a working version:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::colvec test(arma::colvec x, arma::colvec y) {
  arma::colvec out(x.size()*y.size());
  arma::colvec::iterator ix,iy;
  int count=0;
  for (ix=x.begin();ix!=x.end();ix++) {
    for (iy=y.begin();iy!=y.end();iy++) {
      out(count)=*ix+*iy;
      count+=1;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

/*** R
test(c(1:15),c(15:1))
*/
```

This works fine, but I feel like the use of the `count` as an ad-hoc iterator for the out vector seems inelegant, and I feel like there must be a better solution. I was hoping something like this would work:

```
arma::colvec::iterator ix,iy,io;
for (ix=x.begin(),io=out.begin();ix!=x.end(),io!=out.end();ix++,io++) {
  for (iy=y.begin();iy!=y.end();iy++,io++) {
    *io=*ix+*iy;
  }
}
```

This crashes my computer so I am guessing I can't make `io` iterate with each loop. I would be very grateful if someone could indicate what is good practice in situations like this.

Regards

Comment: ` count`  is indeed a makeshift iterator, but its logic is correct. Had you done a straightforward conversion to a real iterator, without adding or moving code, it would have worked. I.e. "Initialize, { use, increment }"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing `io++` two times in a row each time the nested loop finishes. That moves your iterator faster than it should, eventually out of range. **But `ix` goes out of range, too.**

Remove the `io++` from the outer loop's iteration expression. Then it will be equivalent to:

```
*(io++) = *ix + *iy;
```

and no other incrementation of `io`.

Now, **beware the comma operator** in the loop condition (this is what's causing the crash):

```
ix != x.end(), io != out.end()
```

- evaluates `ix != x.end()`, discards its value, uses the value of `io != out.end()`. There should be logical AND (`&&`) instead. And if, you should be checking `io != out.end()` in the condition of the nested loop (that's where `io` gets incremented).

But since you constructed `out` like this:

```
arma::colvec out(x.size() * y.size());
```

It's safe without the check.

Code (C++11):

```
auto io = out.begin();

for (auto x_elem : x)
  for (auto y_elem : y)
    *(io++) = x_elem + y_elem;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be checking `io.end()` at all ! It's dead code, but most likely the compiler fails to optimize it. The reason it's dead is because `io.size()` is sufficient. Had the memory allocation failed, `io` wouldn't have existed at all. (Objects only exist after their ctor returns, not if it throws)

Comment: @MSalters Edited a few seconds ago.